# Collision detection for a circle inside an octagon in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, collision-detection

I am new to JavaFX and am having trouble with the collision detection. I have a circle inside an octagon that I wish to stay inside the octagon by bouncing off the walls. Currently, if I check for collisions inside the key pressed event whenever I try to move the circle it tends to hop around but, if I place the collision check outside the key pressed event nothing happens. At this moment my code only checks for collisions against the left and right wall. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Vector;
import com.sun.javafx.geom.Vec2f;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.LongProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleLongProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Craft extends Application {
double getX; // I later declare this as circ1.getTranslateX()
double getY; // I later declare this as circ1.getTranslateY()

@Override 
public void start(Stage primaryStage) { 

    Pane pane = new Pane();

    Polygon octagon = new Polygon(500,50, 1200,50, 1600,300, 1600,800,        1200,1000, 500,1000, 100,800, 100,300 );
    octagon.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    octagon.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    Circle circ1 = new Circle(500.0f, 500.0f, 25.0f);
    circ1.setFill(Color.BLUE);

    Polygon tri1 = new Polygon(530, 495, 530, 505, 540, 500);
    tri1.setFill(Color.BLUE);
    tri1.translateXProperty().bind(circ1.translateXProperty());
    tri1.translateYProperty().bind(circ1.translateYProperty());

    Rotate rotate = new Rotate();
    rotate.pivotXProperty().bind(circ1.centerXProperty());
    rotate.pivotYProperty().bind(circ1.centerYProperty());
    rotate.angleProperty().bind(circ1.rotateProperty());

    tri1.getTransforms().add(rotate);

    pane.getChildren().addAll(octagon, circ1, tri1);

    getX = circ1.getTranslateX();
    getY = circ1.getTranslateY();

    Bounds bounds = octagon.getBoundsInLocal();
    boolean leftWall = circ1.getTranslateX() <= (bounds.getMinX() +          circ1.getRadius());
    boolean topWall = circ1.getLayoutY() <= (bounds.getMinY() + circ1.getRadius());
    boolean rightWall = circ1.getTranslateX() >= (bounds.getMaxX() + circ1.getRadius());
    boolean bottomWall = circ1.getLayoutY() >= (bounds.getMaxY() + circ1.getRadius());

    circ1.setOnKeyPressed((e) -> {
        if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
            DoubleProperty circ1VelX = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
            DoubleProperty circ1VelY = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
            LongProperty lastUpdateTime = new SimpleLongProperty();
            AnimationTimer circ1Animation = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
              public void handle(long timestamp) {
                if (lastUpdateTime.get() > 0) {
                  double elapsedSeconds = (timestamp - lastUpdateTime.get()) / 1_000_000_000.0 ;
                  double deltaX = elapsedSeconds * circ1VelX.get();
                  double deltaY = elapsedSeconds * circ1VelY.get();
                  double oldX = circ1.getTranslateX();
                  double oldY = circ1.getTranslateY();
                  double newX = oldX + deltaX;
                  double newY = oldY + deltaY;
                  circ1.setTranslateX(newX += 1 * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(circ1.getRotate())) * 0.1);
                  circ1.setTranslateY(newY += 1 * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(circ1.getRotate())) * 0.1);
                }
                lastUpdateTime.set(timestamp);
              }
            };circ1Animation.start();

        }
        else if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) {
            circ1.setRotate(circ1.getRotate() - 5);
        }
        else if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
            circ1.setRotate(circ1.getRotate() + 5);
        }
        else if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
            DoubleProperty circ1VelX = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
            DoubleProperty circ1VelY = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
            LongProperty lastUpdateTime = new SimpleLongProperty();
            AnimationTimer circ1Animation = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
              public void handle(long timestamp) {
                if (lastUpdateTime.get() > 0) {
                  double elapsedSeconds = (timestamp - lastUpdateTime.get()) / 1_000_000_000.0 ;
                  double deltaX = elapsedSeconds * circ1VelX.get();
                  double deltaY = elapsedSeconds * circ1VelY.get();
                  double oldX = circ1.getTranslateX();
                  double oldY = circ1.getTranslateY();
                  double newX = oldX + deltaX;
                  double newY = oldY + deltaY;
                  circ1.setTranslateX(newX -= 1 * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(circ1.getRotate())) * 0.1);
                  circ1.setTranslateY(newY -= 1 * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(circ1.getRotate())) * 0.1);
                }
                lastUpdateTime.set(timestamp);
              }
            };circ1Animation.start();
        }

    });

    circ1.setOnKeyReleased((e) -> {
        if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
            DoubleProperty circ1VelX = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
            DoubleProperty circ1VelY = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
            LongProperty lastUpdateTime = new SimpleLongProperty();
            AnimationTimer circ1Animation = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
              public void handle(long timestamp) {
                if (lastUpdateTime.get() > 0) {
                  double elapsedSeconds = (timestamp - lastUpdateTime.get()) / 1_000_000_000.0 ;
                  double deltaX = elapsedSeconds * circ1VelX.get();
                  double deltaY = elapsedSeconds * circ1VelY.get();
                  double oldX = circ1.getTranslateX();
                  double oldY = circ1.getTranslateY();
                  double newX = oldX + deltaX;
                  double newY = oldY + deltaY;
                  circ1.setTranslateX(newX += 0.5 *      Math.cos(Math.toRadians(circ1.getRotate())));
                  circ1.setTranslateY(newY += 0.5 * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(circ1.getRotate())));
                }
                lastUpdateTime.set(timestamp);
              }
            };circ1Animation.start();
        }
        else if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
            DoubleProperty circ1VelX = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
            DoubleProperty circ1VelY = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
            LongProperty lastUpdateTime = new SimpleLongProperty();
            AnimationTimer circ1Animation = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
              public void handle(long timestamp) {
                if (lastUpdateTime.get() > 0) {
                  double elapsedSeconds = (timestamp - lastUpdateTime.get()) / 1_000_000_000.0 ;
                  double deltaX = elapsedSeconds * circ1VelX.get();
                  double deltaY = elapsedSeconds * circ1VelY.get();
                  double oldX = circ1.getTranslateX();
                  double oldY = circ1.getTranslateY();
                  double newX = oldX + deltaX;
                  double newY = oldY + deltaY;
                  circ1.setTranslateX(newX -= 0.5 * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(circ1.getRotate())));
                  circ1.setTranslateY(newY -= 0.5 *       Math.sin(Math.toRadians(circ1.getRotate())));

                }
                lastUpdateTime.set(timestamp);
              }
            };circ1Animation.start();
        }

    });

    if(leftWall || rightWall) {
          circ1.setTranslateX(getX *= -1);
      }



    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 1700, 1050);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("custom_craft.css");

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Craft");
    primaryStage.show();

    circ1.requestFocus();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're searching for would be answers to several questions, e. g. I guess your ball should move continuously and not stutter while moving. Moreover the ball should move all the time and not only on keypress. And your usage of the AnimationTimer is wrong.

Regarding the intersection: If you'd just have a rectangle, then the answer is easy. But you don't. So you're left with checking either against the octagon or against separate lines. And that itself is very math-y. There are already several questions and answers here on SO regarding line <-> circle intersection. And then you have the matter about the angle of bouncing off your diagonal walls, etc.

Here's a quick & dirty example:

- I convert your polygon into separate lines
- I create a new shape out of the circle and each line and in that way can check whether they intersect or not

You can drag the circle around and see the intersection by the changing color.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CircleLineIntersection extends Application {

    Circle circle;
    List<Line> lines = new ArrayList<>();

    Color defaultStroke = Color.GREEN;
    Color defaultFill = defaultStroke.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.3);

    Color hitStroke = Color.RED;
    Color hitFill = hitStroke.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.3);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Group root = new Group();

        circle = new Circle(100, 100, 50);
        circle.setStroke( defaultStroke);
        circle.setFill( defaultFill);

        Polygon octagon = new Polygon(500, 50, 1200, 50, 1600, 300, 1600, 800, 1200, 1000, 500, 1000, 100, 800, 100, 300);

        // create lines out of the octagon
        int size = octagon.getPoints().size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 2) {

            double startX = octagon.getPoints().get(i);
            double startY = octagon.getPoints().get(i + 1);
            double endX = octagon.getPoints().get((i + 2) % size);
            double endY = octagon.getPoints().get((i + 3) % size);

            Line line = new Line(startX, startY, endX, endY);

            lines.add(line);
        }

        MouseGestures mg = new MouseGestures();
        mg.makeDraggable(circle);

        root.getChildren().addAll(lines);
        root.getChildren().addAll(circle);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1920, 1080));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public class MouseGestures {

        class DragContext {
            double x;
            double y;
        }

        DragContext dragContext = new DragContext();

        public void makeDraggable(Node node) {
            node.setOnMousePressed(onMousePressedEventHandler);
            node.setOnMouseDragged(onMouseDraggedEventHandler);
            node.setOnMouseReleased(onMouseReleasedEventHandler);
        }

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMousePressedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                Circle circle = ((Circle) (event.getSource()));

                dragContext.x = circle.getCenterX() - event.getSceneX();
                dragContext.y = circle.getCenterY() - event.getSceneY();

            }
        };

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseDraggedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                Circle circle = ((Circle) (event.getSource()));

                circle.setCenterX(dragContext.x + event.getSceneX());
                circle.setCenterY(dragContext.y + event.getSceneY());

                // check intersection of lines vs circle
                boolean intersects = false;
                for (Line line : lines) {

                    // TODO: this is heavy on performance, better implement your own line <-> circle intersection algorithm
                    Shape shape = Shape.intersect( line, circle);
                    intersects = shape.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() >= 0 || shape.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight() >= 0;

                    if( intersects) {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // set color depending on intersection
                if( intersects) {
                    circle.setStroke( hitStroke);
                    circle.setFill( hitFill);
                }  else {
                    circle.setStroke( defaultStroke);
                    circle.setFill( defaultFill);
                }

            }
        };

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseReleasedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            }
        };

    }

}
```

Comment: This is awesome, it definitely puts me on the right track. What do you mean my use of animation timer is wrong? I am new to JavaFX.

Comment: You are using the AnimationTimer on every key press. That's wrong. The AnimationTimer should be 1 timer than runs continuously and in that timer you check whether a key was pressed or not, handle the movement, collision, etc. Basically it's your game loop.

Answer (score 0):

I certainly know the awt answer... casting your polygons to areas and using the intersects method.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html

You might have to define a new polygon of some small non zero thickness around your octagon and (Area) new Polygon frame(...)

```
frame.intersect((Area)circ1).isEmpty()!=true
```

The circle and frame have collided.

edit:
[Collision detector in javafx (2d maze)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047379/collision-detector-in-javafx-2d-maze) provides some instruction on dealing with object collision with the javafxCanvas